# Ways of working with Interfaces inheriting Identical Properties in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Let's say I have a "Building Cost" calculation class that takes a list of sub calculators.

The sub calculators all define an interface that define that inputs that are required for that sub calculator. Eg. `IWallsCostInputs`, `IRoofCostInputs`. This allows the sub calculators to express the data they need clearly.

There is a business object that contains the data for all the sub calculators and more (such as DateLastModified etc). Eg. `BuildingCostInputs`.

I would like the `BuildingCostCalculator` to take an interface that defines all the inputs it needs

```
public interface IBuildingCostInputs : IWallsCostInputs, IRoofCostInputs
```

However this doesn't work if there are any duplicate properties in `IWallsCostInputs` and `IRoofCostInputs`.

I think my options are as follows:

1. Use the new keyword in `IBuildingCostInputs`
2. Define an abstract class that implements `IWallsCostInputs` and `IRoofCostInputs`, have `BuildingCostInputs` derive from it and pass it in to `BuildingCostCalculator`.
3. Create a POCO that implements  `IWallsCostInputs` and `IRoofCostInputs`, (auto)map between this and `BuildingCostInputs` and pass this in to `BuildingCostCalculator`.

(1) I think willcause me trouble when I reference a duplicated property through `IWallsCostInputs` and `IRoofCostInputs`, and when using Test Doubles (eg Moq).

(2) doesn't work in may particular case as my business object is already part of an inheritance chain.

(3) does work and it seems like what I will need to do. However I would rather avoid the framework overhead of the mapping and the POCO.

Does anyone have any comments, or have a better way of implementing what I am trying to do? It feels like I should be able to achieve this in a clear, concise and expressive way, but maybe it isn't possible.

Thanks

Comment: Eh, *explicit interface implementation*? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I'm not a fan of explicit interface implementation, and in this case I don't see how it would be better than any of the other options.

Comment: Not familiar with c# or what problem this is trying to solve but this looks totally weird to me, why would you have an  interface (basically) define data structures rather than specify behaviour?

Comment: @blank: These interfaces are basically defining data structures, do you know of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to the property to be the same, you can inherit your interfaces from the same interface.

```
    interface IConstructionInputs
    {
        DateTime DateLastModified { get; }
    }

    interface IRoofCostInputs : IConstructionInputs
    {
    }

    interface IWallCostInputs : IConstructionInputs
    {
    }

    interface IBuildingCostInputs : IRoofCostInputs, IWallCostInputs
    {
    }

    class BuildingCostInputs : IBuildingCostInputs
    {
        public DateTime DateLastModified { get; private set; }
    }
```

Comment: Like it. This might be a bit difficult for me as I have a lot of sub calculators with various duplicated properties and without any obvious potential for categorisation, but this will work and is better than any of my original options. I still feel it should be possible to do something better, but quite possibly it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would rethink whether I need to use inheritance at all. If you had a common interface you could do:

```
public interface IBuildingCostInput
{
     IReadOnlyCollection<ICostInputs> CostInputs {get;}
}
```

or if you wanted to be explicit, perhaps:

```
public interface IBuildingCostInput
{
     IWallsCostInputs WallCostInputs {get;}
     IRoofCostInputs RoofCostInputs {get;}
}
```

Comment: Hi. I would like to pass an object in to BuildingCostCalculator, and then to simply pass this same object on to all the sub calculators. Your second method would work (so thanks for that!) but at the cost of making BuildingCostCalculator a bit more complicated, and the extra framework of implementing IBuildingCostInput. I am not sure how this extra faff compares to my current option 3.